# Issue with published promotions

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

In Fredhopper business manager I can see below warning with every promotion published through Smart target:

> Items with the following ids cannot be found:
>   tcm_54-14212-16_tcm_54-44540-32. Please remove them from your
>   handpicked list.

May be because of that these items are not returning in query resultset.

Is there anyone, who have faced similar error. Can anyone suggest the probable root cause of this issue..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically this means that the component tcm_54-14212-16 combined with its Component Template (CT) tcm_54-44540-32 is not present in the Fredhopper index.

This can happen if you're missing the Add To SmartTarget TBB in your CT, or if your CT is not dynamic, or if the Component is not published.
If you are using specific IDs in the Handpicked list in the definition of your promotion, then try to remove those and only pick items that actually exist in the Fredhopper index.
You can use the FH preview to navigate through your Tridion published content that has been indexed by Fredhopper. If you don't see any of your content there, then most likely the configuration of the smarttarget deployment should be verified.

Comment: Could it also just be a symptom of the content having been _unpublished_? I'd expect that normally no-one would enter such a specific ComonentPresentation ID by accident, but they may well have chosen it from a list in the past and it has since been removed.

Comment: Thanks Philippe, I have verified that the published components were not present in FH preview. When I updated the item with already published ID, warning disappear.